# Countdown timers threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, timer, countdown

I got a problem. I would like to create a program that waits for input while a timer is ongoing. I found out that using sleep doesn't work since it would freeze the program for a fixed time. I don't really understand the time reference as well as the threads reference. I'm doing this in Netbeans in a mac machine.

How can i do this?

Comment: Is this a "console" or "GUI" application?

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes this is a console application

Comment: Then you will struggle to do this using "standard" functions, since the input with for example `cin` or `getline`, etc, is not possible to stop - unless you are going to exit the entire program.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Then there's no point to doing this programme if i cant have input while a timer is counting down. Haiz

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on a Mac your are (most likely) using OSX which is POSIX compatible.

Then you can use e.g. [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) to poll if there is input on standard input. The `select` function conveniently also have timeout functionality.

Can be used something like

```
fd_set input_set;
timeval timeout;

FD_ZERO(&input_set);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_set);

// Set timeout to one minute
timeout.tv_sec  = 60;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

int result = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &input_set, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);

if (result == -1)
    std::cout << "Error in select call: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
else if (result == 0)
{
    // Timeout, do something here
}
else if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_set))
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    // Have input, do something with it
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand this part
`else if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_set))
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    // Have input, do something with it
}`
what does it mean?

Comment: @JoelSeah The `select` call modifies the descriptor sets, and you use the `FD_ISSET` macro/function to check if a descriptor is set in the set. The body part reads a line of input from the standard input stream.

Comment: hmmm. then where can i do the displaying part of the countdown everytime the user enters a input?

Comment: @JoelSeah The code I shown in my answer is only an example. Variants of it can be executed in a loop with a smaller timeout, for example for a countdown.

Comment: What is fd_set, FD_ZERO, FD_SET? and wad does the sign '&' means? sorry for the many questions. I'm new to this.

Comment: @JoelSeah Read the linked reference page. As for the ampersand, it's the address-of operator, and it returns the address of its operand, i.e. it creates a pointer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33402/discussion-between-joel-seah-and-joachim-pileborg)